# Regex to allow only numbers and max 2 digits

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am working on an input field, that should allow users to enter numbers from 0 to 99. In addition the user should not be allowed to type in a 3rd digit.

To tackle the above i have the following regex
`/^([0-9]{2})$/`

I have the following function that is triggered on keypress event

```
    onlyAllowNumbers(evnt: KeyboardEvent): boolean {
        const charCode = evnt.key;
        const pattern = /^([0-9]{2})$/;

        return pattern.test(charCode);
}
```

The above pattern isn't allowing me to enter in any numbers in the input field.

Comment: Because the input is a single char.

Comment: How about `<input type="number" min="0" max="99">` ?

Comment: type=number wont work in firefox, also with that the user can still type in more digits than 2

Comment: If you have a strict requirement on the number length you should not forget to check it on server side, both input field and JavaScript can be bypassed by the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to update regex to allow 0 or 2 digits- `/^[0-9]{0,2}$/`.

The following values will match: '', '0', '1', ... '10', ... '99'.

`keypress` event has the following fields:

- `event.target.value` - value of input before new key was pressed
- `event.key` - string value of the key that was pressed

When `event.target.value` and `event.key` are combined together we can estimate new value of the input.

`event.preventDefault()` call can be used to block keypress event if the resulting value does not match the needed pattern.

```js
document.getElementById('myinput').addEventListener('keypress', event => {
    if (!`${event.target.value}${event.key}`.match(/^[0-9]{0,2}$/)) {
        // block the input if result does not match
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="myinput" type="text" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you will want to use this in a form. If you're targeting modern browsers, the `input` field supports the [pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_pattern.asp) attribute which adds an extra layer of pattern enforcement (in case JavaScript is disabled).

If you're considering the best user experience, you'll also want to anticipate less common use cases. For example: if the user selects one of the digits and types another one, they are indicating they are replacing the selected digit with the new one.

The following code takes all of this into consideration:

```
<form>
  <input id="only_max_two_digits" type="text" pattern="^\d{1,2}$" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function remove_substr(s, src, dst) {
    return s.substr(0, src) + s.substr(dst);
  }

  document
    .querySelector("#only_max_two_digits")
    .addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
      const { value, pattern, selectionStart, selectionEnd } = e.target;
      const next = remove_substr(value, selectionStart, selectionEnd) + e.key;

      if (!new RegExp(pattern).test(next)) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
</script>
```

The function `remove_substr` removes a substring from a string between two given numerical bounds. In this case, we're using it to remove the selected text, because we know where the selection begins and ends.

The event listener:

- It is triggered by the `keypress` event, meaning when the key is down, but the `<input>`'s value has not yet updated.
- The `next` variable contains the estimation of what the next value will be, by 1) removing the currently selected text (if any) and appending the value of the key that is being pressed.
- If the value of the `next` variable doesn't pass the Regex pattern test, `<input>` is prevented from updating.

Here's a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-68627774-v3hhx?file=/index.html) example.

Answer (score 0):

You Must use event value, and I recomend use the regex here in code, the event key for numbers never match the regex cause '1' is only one digit

```
//evnt.key will return you the key pressed value

onlyAllowNumbers(evnt: KeyboardEvent): boolean {
        const value = evnt.target.value;
        const pattern = /^\d{2}$/;

        return pattern.test(value);
}
```